# Building a base 2 exponent calculator in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logarithm

```
log2(I,E):-
  I is 2.0**E,
  E is log(I)/log(2).
```

I am trying to use Prolog to compute either the power 2 was raised to 'I' or 2 raised to the 'E' power equals 'I'. I am extremely new to this language and from my understanding it infers the answer based on the information provided.

```
Queries:
log2(I,3).
-->false.

log2(I,3.0).
-->I = 8.0.

log2(8,E).
-->ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

log2(8,E).
-->ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

I'm confused why I have to provide a float in the first circumstance to get the correct answer and why Prolog is unable to infer the answer from the second circumstance at all.

Comment: Comparing floating point values for equality in any computer language is always a risky business since precision of internal representation can cause an inequality between two numbers that are, in principle, equal. Your second issue, the instantiation error, is because `is/2` requires that *all* variables in the expression have a value in order to compute the expression. So `I is 2.0**E` needs `E` to have a value or you get *Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated*.

Comment: @lurker Ok I understand now that both sides need to have a value, but I still don't understand then how I can get Prolog to infer one value from the other being provided when I can't do what you just described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is a conjunction. In Prolog, a conjunction `a, b` means:

> Evaluate `a`, and if it succeeds, evaluate `b`.

You are trying to do something else, maybe:

> Try `a`, and if it doesn't succeed, try `b`.

The first thing you should consider is using [`library(clpr)`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpqr), if it is available in your Prolog implementation.

With SWI-Prolog:

```
?- use_module(library(clpr)).
true.

?- {I = 2^3}.
I = 8.0 ;
false.

?- {8 = 2^E}.
E = 3.0 ;
false.
```

You literally have no problem any more.

If this is not an option, you need to do something along these lines:

```
log2(I, E) :-
    (   number(I)
    ->  E is /* expression here, now that I is a number */
    ;   number(E)
    ->  I is /* expression here, now that E is a number */
    ;   /* what do you do if both are variables? */
    ).
```

Note that `X is Expr` will work even if `Expr` is an expression and not a number. If you want to allow this, then you need to maybe try `eval(Expr)` first and catch the error or something along these lines.